# Embedding jq in bash - what needs to be escaped?

Tags: bash, escaping, jq, quoting

I'm trying to inline a jq construct that itself requires pipes. I suspect I'm running into issues because bash is treating them as bash-level pipes, rather than part of the jq.

Testing at jqplay.org, this `.[1] | [.timeEnded, .lifecycleState] | flatten` gets me the result I need.

Trying to embed that in bash, I am trying to do something like:

```
status=$(curl -X GET <URL> | jq -r -c '.[1] | [.timeEnded, .lifecycleState] | flatten' | awk -F, '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g')
```

With no escaping the pipes within the jq, I get

```
[.timeEnded,: command not found
```

I tried to escape those pipes as `jq -r -c '.[1] \| [.timeEnded, .lifecycleState] \| flatten'` but that gets me a jq syntax error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[1] \| [.timeEnded, .lifecycleState] \| flatten
jq: 1 compile error
```

Wrapping the entire jq command in double quotes (as well as the escape chars) gave me the same syntax error. I'm sure there's probably an easy answer here, but jq is new to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works for me with the single quotes and no backslashes in jq code. Does the URL contain some suspicious characters?

Comment: The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) is helpful to reference when you're struggling with quoting; it would tell you that within single quotes [*all characters* are treated as literals](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html) which might have helped you see that escaping wasn't the issue in this case. Needless to say unusual whitespace characters are always a *pain* to spot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clearly suspect that you have an *unbreakable space* in this part:

```
jq -r -c '.[1] | [...
```

So, edit the line manually, and replace all spaces with real spaces (taking care to not type *unbreakable spaces* again with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>)

Comment: Dang, that looks like it was the issue. I copied and pasted from jqplay.org, and I guess it inserted something funky. Definitely irritating to spend time trying to figure out escape characters for something that isn't, at all, related to escape characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Embedding jq in bash - what needs to be escaped?

Using bash and bash-like shells, jq programs can often be specified quite simply on the command line using single-quoted strings, e.g.

```
$ jq -n '"abc"'
"abc"
```

However, using this technique, single quotes are a headache since bash
does  not allow single quotes within ordinary single-quoted strings. The workaround is quite horrible:

```
$ jq -n '"a'"'"'b"'
"a'b"
```

So if the jq program does have embedded single-quotes, then
it's probably time to use the -f option, but if that is not
an option, then using the form `$'STRING'` should be considered.

In this case, though, there are two characters that can occur in jq programs and
that will require attention: single-quotes and backslashes

For example:

```
$ jq -n $'"a\\tb" | "\'\\(.)\'"'
"'a\tb'"
```

If I'm not mistaken, the required escaping can be done using:

```
sed -e $'s/\'/\\\'/g' -e $'s/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g'
```